# Using a Filter to redirect after Failed Login Attempt

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, filter

I am using a Java Filter to test for authentication. If the user enters the proper userID and password combination, the filter effectively forwards them to a servlet. However, if the wrong information is input, then the user is sent back to the login page that they came from. For some reason, when they are sent back to the login page, the code for the "login.html" file is shown instead. Here is the code for the filter:

```
package com.simpleServletDemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

/**
 *
 * @author Not Important
 */
@WebFilter("/MyFilterChecker")
public class MyFilterChecker implements Filter {


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String userID = request.getParameter("txtUser");
        String password = request.getParameter("txtPassword");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if (userID.equals("notimpotant@gmail.com") && password.equals("password12345")) {
            out.print("Success!");
            chain.doFilter(request, response); //Sends Request and response to next resource
        } else {
            out.print("Incorrect Username or Password!");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
            dispatcher.include(request, response);
        }
    }


    public void destroy() {        
    }


    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {        

    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks!

I have also included the web.xml file to show mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyLoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.simpleServletDemo.MyLoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyLoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFilterChecker</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.simpleServletDemo.MyFilterChecker</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilterChecker</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: You can forward instead of include- 
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: Use response.sendRedirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your dispatcher.include() method to dispatcher.forward() method. You can also use response.redirect() method to forward to the login.html file.